# Missing flags issue after deploy to heroku

Tags: angular, github, heroku, codeigniter-3, angular6

I am trying to deploy my project build in angular 6 and CI to GitHub and deploy to the heroku. I have successfully deploy but when I try to open to link I get following error:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I have checked the heroku logs, there I find

```
 »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help
```

I am not sure where to fix this.

Can anybody help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case, but I had the same message when running any commands such as checking logs and for me it was because I was executing commands on the Heroku client that was not in the same directory as the one I created the app. From their docs "a git remote (called heroku) is also created and associated with your local git repository". Having followed [this Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#prepare-the-app) when I change directory to "node-js-getting-started.git" it resolved the issue. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Heroku app with

```
heroku create my-app
```

you need to provide the flag (`-a`, `--app`) to the other operations. For instance:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app my-app
```